# DFRobot GPS init error [Arduino Uno, SIM808]

Tags: arduino-uno, communication, gps

i have problem with initialization DFRobot SIM808 actually when i try to recieve gps data by SoftwareSerial only it does works (i mean examples based on sending and reading command to and from serial's), and recieve data but very long string of data and i need only **Latitude** and **Longitude** and i think using DFRobot will be the easiest way to extract the data i need. So the simple test program like this one is not working:

```
    /*
### Get GPS data
1. This example is used to test SIM808 GPS/GPRS/GSM Shield's reading GPS data.
2. Open the SIM808_GetGPS example or copy these code to your project
3. Download and dial the function switch to Arduino
4. open serial helper
4. Place it outside, waiting for a few minutes and then it will send GPS data to serial

create on 2016/09/23, version: 1.0
by jason

*/
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define PIN_TX    7
#define PIN_RX    8
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX,PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,



void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //******** Initialize sim808 module *************
  while(!sim808.init()) { 
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
  }

  //************* Turn on the GPS power************
  if( sim808.attachGPS())
      Serial.println("Open the GPS power success");
  else 
      Serial.println("Open the GPS power failure");

}

void loop() {
   //************** Get GPS data *******************
   if (sim808.getGPS()) {
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.year);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.month);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.day);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.hour);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.minute);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.second);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.centisecond);
    Serial.print("latitude :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lat);
    Serial.print("longitude :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lon);
    Serial.print("speed_kph :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.speed_kph);
    Serial.print("heading :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.heading);
    Serial.println();

    //************* Turn off the GPS power ************
    sim808.detachGPS();
  }

}
```

[image: error]

Comment: `SoftwareSerial` accepts the pins in `RX, TX` order. You have them backwards. This may not  be the issue depending on your wiring, but it's the first thing I noticed.

Comment: yea some mistake in template but it is (7,8) anyways, same as in working example

Comment: I have the same issue were you able to resolve?

Comment: Nope, i just wrote my code instead using library :( . Resolving it would be still useful

Comment: I have tried to run the sim808 shield with the source code from above and also with the Dave's code. Without success. I have the external power supply, I switch between the different modes when uploading the code. I receive on the serial monitor either Sim808 init error
or GPS initializing. Do you have any suggestions where to start troubleshooting?

Comment: I had similar problems, couldn't even get a basic connection from Arduino - Shield. I guess the DF Robot GPRS library is broken.

Comment: @stevieb, well spotted about the TX&RX being the wrong way round in the DFR demo, but sadly that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @OnuralpArslan I have unprotected this question so you can answer it. Your original answer is here as a Community WiKi answer that you can copy and paste into your new answer.

Answer (score 1):

{Original answer by [Onuralp Arslan](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/67787/onuralp-arslan)}

gps function of sim808 does not require sim card you only need 9v source with enough current and 1575.42 mHz gps antenna
use this code it will help

```
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define PIN_RX 11
#define PIN_TX 10
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX,PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,

void setup() {
mySerial.begin(9600);
Serial.begin(9600);

//************* Turn on the GPS power************
if( sim808.attachGPS())
Serial.println("Open the GPS power success");
else
Serial.println("Open the GPS power failure");

}

void loop() {
//************** Get GPS data *******************
if (sim808.getGPS()) {
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.year);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.month);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.day);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.hour);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.minute);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.second);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.centisecond);

Serial.print("latitude :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lat,6);

sim808.latitudeConverToDMS();
Serial.print("latitude :");
Serial.print(sim808.latDMS.degrees);
Serial.print("\^");
Serial.print(sim808.latDMS.minutes);
Serial.print("\'");
Serial.print(sim808.latDMS.seconeds,6);
Serial.println("\"");
Serial.print("longitude :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lon,6);
sim808.LongitudeConverToDMS();
Serial.print("longitude :");
Serial.print(sim808.longDMS.degrees);
Serial.print("\^");
Serial.print(sim808.longDMS.minutes);
Serial.print("\'");
Serial.print(sim808.longDMS.seconeds,6);
Serial.println("\"");

Serial.print("speed_kph :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.speed_kph);
Serial.print("heading :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.heading);

//************* Turn off the GPS power ************
sim808.detachGPS();
}

}
```

try this, worked for me without sim card
connect rx of sim808 to arduino 11
tx to 10
and connect grounds of arduino and sim808

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error in the code. But we managed to solve it! You have to insert the SIM CARD to work. We do not know why, but it works!